# Disable resize of an X11 window

Tags: x11

I am trying to prevent the user from resizing (including maximizing) the window of an X11 application. Can anybody point me in the right direction? Google has not been as helpful as usual. Thanks!

Note: I am not using Qt or any other wrapper, directly using X11 calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do this with `XSetWMNormalHints()`, which specifies what resizing the WM should allow.  If you set the min and max the same as the width, normal WMs will disallow resizing.

Be aware that this is called a hint for a reason; the WM is free to ignore you, and most tiling WMs will.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it had something to do with hints, but didn't see anything directly that made the window resizeable or not.